# SQL: Identifying a Row Closest to a Given Date?

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table (my_table):

```
  id fav_color date_of_entry
1  1       red    2009-01-01
2  1      blue    2010-05-05
3  1       red    2011-01-01
4  2     green    2009-02-02
5  2       red    2010-04-04
6  2      blue    2020-09-09
7  3       red    2009-05-05
8  3      blue    2009-06-06
9  3       red    2010-05-05
```

**My Question:**

- I want to create a variable (var1) corresponding to the favorite color for each ID on 2010-01-01 . Since no one declares their favorite color exactly on 2010-01-01 , I want to find out the color that each ID has the earliest available date before 2010-01-01.
- I want to also create a new variable (var2) that is 1 is var1 = red else 0

The final answer should look like this:.

```
  id fav_color date_of_entry  var1 var2
1  1       red    2009-01-01   red    1
2  1      blue    2010-05-05   red    1
3  1       red    2011-01-01   red    1
4  2     green    2009-02-02 green    0
5  2       red    2010-04-04 green    0
6  2      blue    2020-09-09 green    0
7  3       red    2009-05-05  blue    0
8  3       red    2009-06-06  blue    0
9  3       red    2010-05-05  blue    0
```

**Here is my attempt to do this:**

```
    WITH temp AS (
        SELECT id, fav_color, date_of_entry,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_of_entry DESC) AS row_num
        FROM my_table
 WHERE date_of_entry < '2010-01-01'
    )
    SELECT my_table.id, my_table.fav_color, my_table.date_of_entry, temp.fav_color AS var1,
    CASE WHEN temp.fav_color = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS var2
    FROM my_table
    LEFT JOIN temp
    ON my_table.id = temp.id AND temp.row_num = 1;
```

**But my final answer does not match the desired output:**

```
  id fav_color date_of_entry var1 var2
1  1       red    2009-01-01  red    1
2  1      blue    2010-05-05  red    1
3  1       red    2011-01-01  red    1
4  2     green    2009-02-02 blue    0
5  2       red    2010-04-04 blue    0
6  2      blue    2020-09-09 blue    0
7  3       red    2009-05-05  red    1
8  3      blue    2009-06-06  red    1
9  3       red    2010-05-05  red    1
```

**Can someone please show me how to fix this?**

Thanks!

**Note:**

Here is the data for the question:

```
my_table = (
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
fav_color = c("red", "blue", "red", "green", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "red"),
date_of_entry = c("2009-01-01", "2010-05-05", "2011-01-01", "2009-02-02", "2010-04-04", "2020-09-09", "2009-05-05", "2009-06-06", "2010-05-05")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CTE, you should also filter off any records occurring *after* `2010-01-01`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, fav_color, date_of_entry,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_of_entry DESC) AS rn
    FROM my_table
    WHERE date_of_entry <= '2010-01-01'
)

SELECT id, fav_color, date_of_entry,
       CASE WHEN fav_color = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS var2
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! But I also want to keep ALL records from the original table, and just create new variables to "flag" these conditions .... your SQL code is not keeping all the records. Is there a way to change this?